# Como fazer um loop foreach com limite em c#?

Tags: c#, .net, loop

Como posso fazer um loop foreach com limite, por exemplo eu tenho um dicionario com 100 itens e quero fazer um loop do item 20 até o 50 como posso fazer isso no c#.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simples,tente os seguinte códigos como exemplos :

**Foreach exemplo 1 :**

```
foreach(ListViewItem lvi in listView.Items.Skip(20))
{
   //faça algo
   if (++itens == 50) break;
}
```

**Foreach exemplo 2 :**

```
foreach(var itens in dicionario.Items.Skip(20).Take(50))
```

**For :**

```
for(int itens = 20; i <= 50 && i < dicionario.Items.Count; i++)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = dicionario.Items[i];
}
```

**LINQ :**

```
foreach( ListViewItem lvi in dicionario.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Skip(20).Take(50))
{
    //faça algo
}
```

Para melhores esclarecimentos,dê uma olhada na documentação do `foreach` [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements) e do `for` [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements).

E para melhor entendimento dos métodos `Skip()` e `Take()` dê uma olhada [aqui](https://web.archive.org/web/20200813151124/http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/03/29/c.net-little-wonders-skip-and-take.aspx).